# Me and Eclipse do not agree on how many processes are using my files

Tags: java, file, process, filesystemexception

Seems a bizarre question, but me and Eclipse have divergent opinions about it. I continue to get the error message `java.nio.file.FileSystemException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` even if the `main()` method should have only one thread, one process.

Given a list of files, my program essentially does two things:

- For each and every file, creates a .txt file with information about the file (the .txt is called a "substitute")
- For each and every file, the file is moved into another directory.

If I use comments to execute first the first thing, then the second, nothing untoward happens. The moment in which I try doing both things, one after the other, moving the files returns the aforementioned exception. I have no idea why it happens or how to put an end to it. I hope someone here has ideas.

---

Here the code. I included all the methods used, including a few written for my custom libraries (usually added to deal with exceptions).

Edit: simplified the code for minimal reproducible example

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File[] files = new File[] {
        //      new File(""),
        };
        File directoryWhereToPutSubstitutes = new File("");
        File directoryWhereToMoveTheOriginalFiles = new File("");
        
        createSubstiteFileForCancelledWav( 
                directoryWhereToPutSubstitutes,
                files,
                "The stock appended message to append to the content of each and every substitute. It specifies why the file needs a substitute. "
                );
        //  */  // this method gives problems at the following one
        //      // the error returned is:
//      java.nio.file.FileSystemException: originalFile -> fileDestination: Impossibile accedere al file. Il file è utilizzato da un altro processo.
                    // Error message in english:    The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
        
        
          
        // TODO | Moving useless file
        for(File file : files)
            {
            System.out.println("MOVING " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            /*FileManager.*/moveFile(file, directoryWhereToMoveTheOriginalFiles);
            }
        
        
    }
    
    // =====================================
        // TODO | First method
    
    public static void createSubstiteFileForCancelledWav(File directory, File[] files, String appendedMessage) {
        int recordNumber, endIndex;
        File substitute;
        Matcher matcher;
        for( File file : files )
            if( file.getName().endsWith(".wav") )
                {
                // Check if the file must be substituted
                
                // If it must be substitutes...
                
                // ...create a txt file with the appropriate name
                String nameSubstituteFile = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")) + " - substitute.txt";
                
                // ...and put the information of the file in the 
                createFileAndWriteTextInIt(
                        directory, 
                        nameSubstituteFile, 
                        recordInformation(file, appendedMessage)
                        );
                }
    }
    
    
    
    
    public static void createFileAndWriteTextInIt(File directory, String fileName, String text) {
        File file = directory.toPath().resolve(fileName).toFile();
        
        /*FileManager.*/ // createNewFile_nio(file);
        if( !Files.notExists(file.toPath(), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)  )
            System.out.println("THE DESTINATION FILE (" + file.getAbsolutePath() + ") ALREADY EXISTS");
        else if( file.isFile() )
            {
            System.out.println("Trying to create the file " + file.getAbsolutePath() + "...");
            // Creates the directories in the file pathname that still do not exist
            try {   Files.createDirectories(file.toPath().getParent());     } catch (Exception e) {             e.printStackTrace();        }
            // Creates the file itself
            try {   Files.createFile(file.toPath());        } catch (Exception e) {             e.printStackTrace();        }
            }
        
        PrintStream stream = null;
        try {   stream = new PrintStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         e.printStackTrace();        }
        stream.println(text);
        stream.close();
        
    }
    public static String recordInformation(File file, String appendedMessage) {
        StringBuffer support = new StringBuffer();
        
        support.append(/*TestLibraries.*/getFileInfo(file)).append("\n");
        support.append("Record line:").append("\n");
        support.append(
                /*registerLine(isTAC, recordNumber)*/
                "In my complete program, the files are not casual: each has a record number, clearly identifiable in the file name, "
                + "and a record line stored in a .txt database. The registerLine() method seeks the record line from the record number, "
                + "but since neither the variable file nor the actual file are involved in any way, shape, or form, "
                + "said method has been omitted in this example. "
                ).append("\n");
        support.append("\n " + appendedMessage).append("\n");
        
        return support.toString();
    }
    
    
    
    // TODO | Legacy methods from personal libraries - for method 1
    
    public static String getFileInfo(File file) {
        StringBuffer support = new StringBuffer();
        
        BasicFileAttributes attrs;
        String creationDate = null, lastModificationDate = null, lastAccessDate = null;
        try {
            attrs = Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
            FileTime time;
            
            time = attrs.creationTime();
            creationDate = simpleDateFormat.format( new Date( time.toMillis() ) );
            
            time = attrs.lastModifiedTime();
            lastModificationDate = simpleDateFormat.format( new Date( time.toMillis() ) );
            
            time = attrs.lastAccessTime();
            lastAccessDate = simpleDateFormat.format( new Date( time.toMillis() ) );
            
            } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {     e.printStackTrace();        }
              catch (SecurityException e) {                 e.printStackTrace();        }
              catch (IOException e) {                       e.printStackTrace();        }
        
        support.append("Name of file: \t\t"             + file.getName()                                        + "\n"  );
        support.append("Pathname of file: \t\t"         + file.getAbsolutePath()                                + "\n"  );
        support.append("Creation date: \t\t"            + creationDate          + "\n"  );
        support.append("Last modification date: \t"     + lastModificationDate  + "\n"  );
        support.append("Last access date: \t\t"         + lastAccessDate            + "\n"  );
        
        if( file.getName().endsWith(".wav") )
            {
            support.append("File type: \taudio\n");
            
            double  seconds = /*AudioInformation.*/getDurationOfWavInSeconds(file),
                    minutes = seconds / 60,     // we obtain the duration in minutes rounded down
                    hours = minutes / 60;       // we obtain the duration in hours rounded down
            
            support.append("Duration: \t" 
                    + Integer.toString((int) hours) + "h"
                    + Integer.toString((int) minutes %60) + "m"             // we obtain the number displayed in the 'minutes' section of the duration
                    + Integer.toString(((int) seconds)%60  ) + "s \n"       // we obtain the number displayed in the 'second' section of the duration
                    );
            
            
            
            String[] lastMod = lastModificationDate
                    .split(" ")[1].split("-");
            long lastModFromMidnight = Integer.valueOf(lastMod[0]) *60*60 
                                        + Integer.valueOf(lastMod[1]) *60 
                                        + Integer.valueOf(lastMod[2]) ;
            
            // Gets the number of seconds from midnight that this file has been started (obtained from: seconds file creation - seconds file length)
            seconds = lastModFromMidnight - seconds;
        //  System.out.println("File: " + file.getName() + " \n\t lastModFromMidnight = " + lastModFromMidnight + ", seconds = " + seconds);
            // Converts the above variable in the h-m-s format
            minutes = seconds / 60;
            hours = minutes / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            minutes = minutes % 60;
            
            support.append("Estimated hour of record start: \t" 
                    + Integer.toString((int) hours) + "-"
                    + Integer.toString((int) minutes) + "-"
                    + Integer.toString(((int) seconds)  ) + " \n"
                    );
            }
        
        return support.toString();
    }
    public static double getDurationOfWavInSeconds(File file){
        AudioInputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
            stream.close();
            return file.length() / format.getSampleRate() / (format.getSampleSizeInBits() / 8.0) / format.getChannels();
            }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) 
            {       System.err.println("File: " + file.getAbsolutePath());  e.printStackTrace();        }
        catch (IOException e) 
            {       System.err.println("File: " + file.getAbsolutePath());  e.printStackTrace();        }
        finally 
            {       if(stream!=null)    
                        try { stream.close(); } 
                        catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }                }
        return -1;
    }
    
    
    // =====================================
        // TODO | Second method - Legacy methods from personal libraries 
    
    public static File moveFile(File toBeMoved, File destination, CopyOption... options) {
        return moveFile(toBeMoved, destination, toBeMoved.getName(), options);
    }
    public static File moveFile(File toBeMoved, File directory, String newName, CopyOption... options) {
        // Checking conditions
        if( directory != null && directory.exists() && directory.isDirectory() )
            {
            boolean canMove = true;
            for(File fileInDestination : directory.listFiles())
                if( fileInDestination.getName().equals(newName) )
                    {
                    canMove = false;
                    break;
                    }
                
            if( canMove )       
                try {
                    
                    // Executing action
                    Files.move(         // can cause java.nio.file.FileSystemException: origin -> destin: 
                                                    //      Impossibile accedere al file. Il file è utilizzato da un altro processo.
                //  Files.copy(
                        Paths.get(toBeMoved.getAbsolutePath()), 
                        Paths.get(directory.getAbsolutePath()).resolve(newName),
                        options
                        );
                //  Files.delete(toBeMoved.toPath());
                    return Paths.get(directory.getAbsolutePath()).resolve(toBeMoved.getName()).toFile();
                    } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {           e.printStackTrace();            }
                      catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException e) {    e.printStackTrace();            }
                      catch (SecurityException e) {             e.printStackTrace();            }
                      catch (FileSystemException e) {           e.printStackTrace();
                                                                // The following lines have been added so to better analyze what the problem is... with little to no success
                                                                System.err.println("Reason for failure:\t" + e.getReason()
                                                                + "\nWhole message:" + e.getMessage()); 
                                                                String s = null;
                                                                s.charAt(0);
                                                                }
                      catch (IOException e) {                   e.printStackTrace();            }
            }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a [mcve]? That's too much code for us to wade through, and if you try to code a minimal sample that reproduces the problem you'll likely find the solution yourself.  BTW, the answer is either a resource leak (not closing a file) and/or some other process has the file open.  SysInternals Process Explorer can search open file handles.

Comment: just assume your computer can check whether there are some obscure processes running that use that file

Comment: @JimGarrison removed a few methods copy-pasted from personal libraries - after I confirmed they were not the cause of the error.

Comment: I have already checked resource leaks: of course it is always possible I missed one, but I am reasonably sure that is not the problem. Following your suggestion, I installed and used SysInternals Process Explorer, but unfortunately the JVM is not using the files *at all* when Eclipse is returning an exception, so no dice with it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your example, I don't see such error.

Try to run this example yourself, if an error is still there - it is IDE/OS issue.

If not - the issue is with the code you have not provided (like file reading part, or part where you check the file if it has to be moved, or any other you have not mentioned)